# freebsd server can't connect to internet when static ip is assigned

Tags: networking, ip, freebsd, isp

I have a freeBSD server that worked fine in its old location, but I moved it to a new location with a new ISP and a new static IP address.  I replaced the old static IP with the new static IP in /etc/rc.conf .  I also changed the netmask and defaultrouter to new addresses (given to me by isp).  I then changed the nameserver addresses in /etc/resolv.conf

```
machinename# /etc/rc.d/netif restart

machinename# ping www.google.com

ping: cannot resolve www.google.com: Host name lookup failure.
```

I have two network cards rl0 and xl0 and after entering

```
machinename# /etc/rc.d/netif restart
```

only lo0 and xl0 show up.  rl0 is missing.

I have tried two different network topologies

1. modem --> freeBSD server --> router (topology at previous location)
2. modem --> router --> freeBSD server (with port forwarding enabled on router)

Comment: Can you post the output of ifconfig? It could be a hardware problem. (network card unseated).

Comment: @Hennes result of ping 8.8.8.8 is "ping: sendto: No route to host" (and you are correct it is rl0 and xl0. that changes things dramatically! )

Comment: `No route to host`. What are thew routing tables? Please add the output from `netstat -rn` to the post using the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/659897/edit) link.

Comment: @RolandSmith I'll have to get a usb stick and copy the output because I don't have connectivity on the freeBSD machine. I'll do that soon.  I think the cards are seated because when I change the IPs in rc.conf that change shows up in the output of ifconfig

Comment: @Hennes My mistake the the changes were made in resolv.conf  I'll post soon with the output of ifconfig and netstat -rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.  My network topology has changed from

```
modem --> server --> router
```

to

```
modem --> router --> server
```

So I needed to assign a local static IP 192.168.1.3 rather than my external IP.

@Darius provided me with an answer [unable to assign external static IP ( /etc/init.d/networking restart hangs )](https://superuser.com/questions/660394/unable-to-assign-external-static-ip-etc-init-d-networking-restart-hangs)